# Using an API in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, api

I'm new to React Native and I wanted to make a simple app using [Marvel API](http://developer.marvel.com/) and for that I'm using [API wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marvel-api). I want to display infinite scroll view using VirtualizedList. And here is the question: what to pass in renderItem and data components? And is the 'findCharacters' const good written or should i change something? And lastly, should I change VirtualizedList to FlatList or ScrollView? My code is below

```
   const findCharacters = marvel.characters.findAll()
  .then(console.log)
  .fail(console.error)
  .done();


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <VirtualizedList
      data={/* what to pass here? */}
      renderItem={/* what to pass here? */} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a good idea to use meaningful variable names, in your case something like `getMarvelCharacters` sounds good.

API response gives out a JSON containing `data` which is an array of objects of marvel characters. Pass this to VirtualizedList's `data` param.

As for the `renderItem` prop it's basically about how you want to render each of the objects in `data` i.e marvel characters. Read the full documentation for VirtualizedList over [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/virtualizedlist).

So the whole code can be something like this.

```
const [marvelCharacters, setMarvelCharacters] = useState([]);

const getMarvelCharacters = marvel.characters.findAll()
  .then((err, results) => {
    setMarvelCharacters(results.data);
  })
  .fail(console.error)
  .done();

useEffect(() => {
  getMarvelCharacters();
}, []);

const CharacterItem = ({ title }) => (
  <View>
    <Text>{title}</Text>
  </View>
);

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <VirtualizedList
      data={marvelCharacters}
      renderItem={({ item }) => <CharacterItem title={item.title}/>} />}
    </View>
  );
```